# An <input /> inside a child span is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I am currently trying to access the classNameHTML input in this element:

```
<div id="1">
      <span>
          <input name="classNameHTML" type="text" />
      <span>
</div>
```

The code I currently wrote is

```
let cObj = document.getElementById(1);
let cObjClass = cObj.children[0].classNameHTML.value; <--- buggy line
```

Error Message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at calcGrade (index.html:172)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:243)
```

I was thinking that children[0] would reference the span, and then I can use the reference classNameHTML via its input name. The console says that clasNameHTML is undefined when I did console.log(). Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong with the dot operator here?

Comment: What exactly is `classNameHTML` suppossed to be?  Ooooooh, it's the name of the input.  Instead of doing that, you should either navigate into the children of the children[0], or just use a querySelector of `document.getElementById('1').querySelector('input[name="classNameHTML"]').value` or something of that nature

Comment: `console.log(cObj.children[0])` <-- is it what you expect it to be? There are better ways to access elements.

Comment: You should select by attribute name as your "classNameHTML" is the value of "name" attribute. You may use .querySelectorAll('[name="classNameHTML"]');

Comment: Damn I didn't think of using querySelector

Comment: It works guys, thanks so much :D

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned:

```
let cObjClass = cObj.children[0].classNameHTML.value;
```

is invalid. Breaking it down:

`coObj` is the surrounding div.

`.children[0]` is the span inside the div.

`.classNameHTML` is a property by that name belonging to the span. This does not exist.

You want the input that's inside the span. This will get you to the input:

```
cObj.children[0].firstChild
```

Then, the value of the input as the first child of the span is:

```
cObj.children[0].firstChild.value
```

But in case you want to access the input by name instead of its position, use:

```
cObj.children[0].querySelector('[name="classNameHTML"]').value
```

This will obtain the element inside the span with `name="classNameHTML"`.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get the className from an element you should use .className instead of .classNameHTML.value